# WPF Binding not working unless used with async code

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, binding

I have a Label with the Content property bound to a string on a ViewModel (Prism/MVVM). When I run this method, assigning "pending" to that string, the value changes, but the view never updates. It does update on the second assignment ("success") though.
I fiddled around trying to force an update with RaisePropertyChanged with no success then tried running parts of the code async. That worked!?! - but I have no clue why. Any Idieas on this problem? Any remedy without the async workaround?

XAML:

```
<Label
     Content="{Binding DbaseCreateSuccess, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</Label>
```

Method sync:

```
private void DbaseCreate()
{
    DbaseCreateSuccess = "pending";

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Scripts", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    String databaseName = "testbase";
    String databaseScript = "testbase.sql";
    int fileCount = 0;

        foreach (String file in files)
        {
            if (file.Contains(databaseScript))
            {
                DataService.Runscript(file);
            }
        }

        foreach (String file in files)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
            Trace.WriteLine("FileExtension: " + info.Extension);

            if (info.Extension == ".sql" && !file.Contains(databaseScript))
            {
                ++fileCount;
                DataService.Runscript(file, databaseName);
            }
        }

    if (DataService.GetTableNames(databaseName).Count == fileCount)
    {
        DbaseCreateSuccess = "success";
    }
```

Method async:

```
private async void DbaseCreate()
{
    DbaseCreateSuccess = "pending";

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Scripts", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    String databaseName = "testbase";
    String databaseScript = "testbase.sql";
    int fileCount = 0;

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach (String file in files)
        {
            if (file.Contains(databaseScript))
            {
                DataService.Runscript(file);
            }
        }

        foreach (String file in files)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
            Trace.WriteLine("FileExtension: " + info.Extension);

            if (info.Extension == ".sql" && !file.Contains(databaseScript))
            {
                ++fileCount;
                DataService.Runscript(file, databaseName);
            }
        }
    });

    if (DataService.GetTableNames(databaseName).Count == fileCount)
    {
        DbaseCreateSuccess = "success";
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class DatabaseAdminViewModel : BindableBase
 {

    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    private String _DbaseCreateSuccess;
    public String DbaseCreateSuccess { get { return _DbaseCreateSuccess; } set { SetProperty(ref _DbaseCreateSuccess, value, "DbaseCreateSuccess"); } }

    public DelegateCommand DbaseCreateCommand { get; set; }


    public DatabaseAdminViewModel(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _container = container;

        DbaseCreateSuccess = "idle";

        DbaseCreateCommand = new DelegateCommand(DbaseCreate);

    }

    private async void DbaseCreate()
    {
        DbaseCreateSuccess = "pending";

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Scripts", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        String databaseName = "testbase";
        String databaseScript = "testbase.sql";
        int fileCount = 0;

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (String file in files)
            {
                if (file.Contains(databaseScript))
                {
                    DataService.Runscript(file);
                }
            }

            foreach (String file in files)
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
                Trace.WriteLine("FileExtension: " + info.Extension);

                if (info.Extension == ".sql" && !file.Contains(databaseScript))
                {
                    ++fileCount;
                    DataService.Runscript(file, databaseName);
                }
            }
        });

        if (DataService.GetTableNames(databaseName).Count == fileCount)
        {
            DbaseCreateSuccess = "success";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your viewmodel?

Comment: Any Idieas on this problem? - long running db operation is performed in UI thread and blocks UI. Any remedy without the async workaround? - no

Comment: Seems to be so ASh,  So the triggering of the view change doesn't  happen until after the code has continued executing?